# Permission_denied to access firebase datastore

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am trying to get access to my firebase data to run a little test. I have setup an app in the firebase console and set the access rules to:

```
// Allow read/write access to all users under any conditions 
// Warning: **NEVER** use this rule set in production; it allows
// anyone to overwrite your entire database.
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Nevertheless I am always getting the following error:

```
angular.js:14328 Error: permission_denied at /messages: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.
```

at this line of code:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('messages');
```

What I am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those rules are for firestore and not firebase-realtime database.

In the console go to the database section and click on the dropdown then choose RealTime database:

[image]

For the realtime database change your rules to this:

```
 {
 "rules": {
   ".read": true,
   ".write": true
  }
}
```

and then perform the tests.

Comment: It doesn't allow me in Firestore Realtime database. If I try to set your proposed rules I get: Line 1: mismatched input '{' expecting {'function', 'service', 'syntax'}

Comment: please check the image, in your code you are using firebase realtime database and not firestore api

Comment: Check this https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start#initialize_the_javascript_sdk the `database()` method here is in the realtime database API, so you need to choose in the database console the realtime database and change the rules as above

Comment: There are two different services, one is called firestore and the other is realtime database (it's not the same one)