# Firebase - write new data to database from web application form

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've written a fairly simple form to be sent to my Firebase database, but my database doesn't seem to be updating with the new data from my `submit.html` page. I'm quite new to Firebase, and I've referenced the documentation, but I'm sure I've overlooked something. For testing purposes, the web application at this stage is meant to simply send a first and last name to my database, listed under a collection named `graduate`.

I also want to assign it a unique documentID/Auto-ID. Per the [Firebase documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html#section-push):

> [...] the Firebase JavaScript clients provide a push() function that
>   generates a unique ID, or key, for each new child. By using unique
>   child keys, several clients can add children to the same location at
>   the same time without worrying about write conflicts.

This seems to be exactly what I'm looking for, and so I've included the push call with my function below.

I should also probably mentioned that I've written the following rule for my database:

```
{
  /* Visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security to learn more about security rules. */
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Anyway, here is my code:

My `HTML`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Student Tracking</title>
        <script src="authentication.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cormorant|Roboto:100" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container">
            <header>
                <img src="logo.png" class="logo">
                <h1 class="englogo">Department of English</h1>
                <div class="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="submit.html">Submit</a></li>
                        <li><a href="query.asp">Query</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="contentform">
                    <form id="newUserForm">
                        <h3>Complete the following form to add your student information
                            to the database.
                        </h3>
                        <label for="Field1">First Name:</label><br>
                        <input id="userfName" name="Field1" type="text" value=""><br><br>
                        <label for="Field2">Last Name:</label><br>
                        <input id="userlName" name="Field2" type="text" value=""><br><br>
                        <label for="Field3"></label><br>
                        <input id="saveForm" name="saveForm" type="button" value="Submit Form">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My `app.js`:

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "apiKey",
    authDomain: "authDomain",
    databaseURL: "url",
    projectId: "proID",
    storageBucket: "SB",
    messagingSenderId: "sendID"
    };
firebase.initializeApp(config);

var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child('graduate');

$('#saveForm').click(function(){
    rootRef.push().set({

        firstName:$('#userfName').val(),
        lastName:$('#userlName').val()
    });
})
```

My CSS:

```
.logo {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto 0;
}

.google {
    color: #0099CC; 
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #0099CC;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

.nav {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    padding: 60px 20px 15px 10px;
    text-align: right;
    z-index: 1;
    background: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.3em;
}

.nav li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    margin: 4px;
}

h1.englogo {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 1%;
    font-family: 'Cormorant', serif;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 15px;
}

header {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    position: fixed;
    border-bottom: solid thin;
    background-color: white;
}

#content {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
    height: 1500px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

#contentForm {
    widows: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 150px;
    height: 1500px;
}

form {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 90px;
    height: 1500px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: There are a few problems here. 1) your rules require the user to be logged in, but you don't use Firebase Authentication anywhere. See [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start) to get started 2) you're using the Realtime Database, but are showing security rules for Cloud Firestore. While both databases are part of Firebase, they are completely separate, and the security rules for one have no influence on the other. To set the correct security rules, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52126720/firebase-chat-app-setvalue-failed-error-with-a-public-database/52129163#52129163

Comment: Firebase authentication happens on the `index.html` page, which redirects to `home.html`. Also, switching to Realtime and changing the rules unfortunately did not fix my problem.

Comment: You may still have a problem, but changing the wrong rules definitely would also ensure it didn't work. If you show your new rules, I can check and (of they're indeed seem correct) vote to reopen the question.

Comment: My rules have been updated in the original post.

Comment: With those rules there is no way that they'll reject the write operation. If you set a breakpoint on `rootRef.push().set({`, does it actually hit that code? Also: if you replace the current write with `rootRef.push(true);`, does the write make it to the database?

Comment: As far as I can tell through my debugging in Chrome, it does hit the code and the write doesn't make it to the database.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a site like jsbin or jsfiddle, so we can have a look at it?

Comment: I've never used jsbin before, but I can try: https://jsbin.com/mocexujuya/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'm not sure how this happened, but when I clicked on arrow in the upper right hand corner of my output section of jsbin, and then hit submit, my data was successfully sent to the database. But it still doesn't work outside of that? Could my CSS be interfering? I've added it to my original post.

Comment: CSS has no effect on this JavaScript.

Comment: Then I'm quite confused as to why it works in jsbin but not on my server. Very strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make my program work. Per [this site](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-jquery), I needed to move my `.js` files outside of the head. I moved them right before the closing body tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Department of English | Student Tracking</title>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.3/firebase.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cormorant|Roboto:100" rel="stylesheet">
       <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container">
            <header>
                <img src="olemiss.png" class="logo">
                <h1 class="englogo">Department of English</h1>
                <div class="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="submit.html">Submit</a></li>
                        <li><a href="query.asp">Query</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                    <form id="newUserForm">
                        <h3>Complete the following form to add your student information
                            to the database.
                        </h3>
                        <label for="Field1">First Name:</label><br>
                        <input id="userfName" name="Field1" type="text" value=""><br><br>
                        <label for="Field2">Last Name:</label><br>
                        <input id="userlName" name="Field2" type="text" value=""><br><br>
                        <fieldset>
                                <legend>Program</legend>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                      <label for="title_1">
                                        <input type="radio" id="undergraduate" name="title" value="Undergraduate" >
                                        Undergraduate
                                      </label>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                      <label for="title_2">
                                        <input type="radio" id="graduate" name="title" value="Graduate">
                                        Graduate
                                      </label>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                        </fieldset><br>
                        <label for="Field3">Graduate Year (XXXX):</label><br>
                        <input id="gradDate" name="Field3" type="text" value=""><br><br>

                        <input id="saveForm" name="saveForm" type="submit" value="Submit Form">
                    </form>
            </header>
        </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="authentication.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your root reference might be off. Maybe try this:

```
var ref = firbase.database().ref(<ROOT_REF>)
var rootRef = ref.child('graduate')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have changed the authorization in the database, by default it only allows writing when the user is logged in.