# Error: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, firebase-security

I've been working on this for perhaps a day but I can't get it to work at all. I set up a database with no security rules:

[image]

Then I try to access it in my angular fire app:

```
this.afDatabase
    .object("/test/test")
    .snapshotChanges()
    .subscribe(x => {
        console.log(x);
    });
```

But I still get the following permission errors:

> Error: permission_denied at /test/test: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.

I also ran the simulator and got successful results:

[image]

I also set up my environment.ts file:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You get that when the node you're reading from isn't there. Is that the case?

Comment: The security rules you're showing apply to Cloud Firestore, while the Your use of `object()` seems to indicate that you're using the Realtime Database. While both databases are part of Firebase, they're completely separate, and the security for one don't apply to the other. To fix the error, you will have to set the rules for the Realtime Database. For a walkthrough of how to do that, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52129163

Comment: Thank you! I was referencing the wrong database technology.

Answer (score -3):

This is an issue on firebase side. You need to update Real-time database rules:

```
"rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
```

Comment: Actually it isn't solution for this question