# Unable to save user in Firebase Database iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have developed a Instagram Application Clone and registered the app in Firebase too, Generated and Added "GoogleService Plist". I was successful in running the application in the simulator but when i am trying to register through the application it is showing :

```
    2020-04-17 18:24:41.154861+0530 IrinaGram[47884:2232371] 5.8.0 - [Firebase/Database][I-RDB038012] updateChildValues: at /users failed: permission_denied
Failed to upload user to database: Error Domain=com.firebase Code=1 "Permission denied" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Permission denied}
```

The following code is for FireBase for adding user, likes , comments etc

```
   import Foundation
import Firebase

extension Auth {
    func createUser(withEmail email: String, username: String, password: String, image: UIImage?, completion: @escaping (Error?) -> ()) {
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Failed to create user:", err)
                completion(err)
                return
            }
            guard let uid = user?.user.uid else { return }
            if let image = image {
                Storage.storage().uploadUserProfileImage(image: image, completion: { (profileImageUrl) in
                    self.uploadUser(withUID: uid, username: username, profileImageUrl: profileImageUrl) {
                        completion(nil)
                    }
                })
            } else {
                self.uploadUser(withUID: uid, username: username) {
                    completion(nil)
                }
            }
        })
    }
    
    private func uploadUser(withUID uid: String, username: String, profileImageUrl: String? = nil, completion: @escaping (() -> ())) {
        var dictionaryValues = ["username": username]
        if profileImageUrl != nil {
            dictionaryValues["profileImageUrl"] = profileImageUrl
        }
        
        let values = [uid: dictionaryValues]
        Database.database().reference().child("users").updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Failed to upload user to database:", err)
                return
            }
            completion()
        })
    }
}

extension Storage {
    
    fileprivate func uploadUserProfileImage(image: UIImage, completion: @escaping (String) -> ()) {
        guard let uploadData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1) else { return } //changed from 0.3
        
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_images").child(NSUUID().uuidString)
        
        storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (_, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Failed to upload profile image:", err)
                return
            }
            
            storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (downloadURL, err) in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Failed to obtain download url for profile image:", err)
                    return
                }
                guard let profileImageUrl = downloadURL?.absoluteString else { return }
                completion(profileImageUrl)
            })
        })
    }
    
    fileprivate func uploadPostImage(image: UIImage, filename: String, completion: @escaping (String) -> ()) {
        guard let uploadData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1) else { return } //changed from 0.5
        
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("post_images").child(filename)
        storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (_, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Failed to upload post image:", err)
                return
            }
            
            storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (downloadURL, err) in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Failed to obtain download url for post image:", err)
                    return
                }
                guard let postImageUrl = downloadURL?.absoluteString else { return }
                completion(postImageUrl)
            })
        })
    }
}

extension Database {

    //MARK: Users
    
    func fetchUser(withUID uid: String, completion: @escaping (User) -> ()) {
        Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            guard let userDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
            let user = User(uid: uid, dictionary: userDictionary)
            completion(user)
        }) { (err) in
            print("Failed to fetch user from database:", err)
        }
    }
    
    func fetchAllUsers(includeCurrentUser: Bool = true, completion: @escaping ([User]) -> (), withCancel cancel: ((Error) -> ())?) {
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users")
        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            guard let dictionaries = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else {
                completion([])
                return
            }
            
            var users = [User]()
            
            dictionaries.forEach({ (key, value) in
                if !includeCurrentUser, key == Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
                    completion([])
                    return
                }
                guard let userDictionary = value as? [String: Any] else { return }
                let user = User(uid: key, dictionary: userDictionary)
                users.append(user)
            })
            
            users.sort(by: { (user1, user2) -> Bool in
                return user1.username.compare(user2.username) == .orderedAscending
            })
            completion(users)
            
        }) { (err) in
            print("Failed to fetch all users from database:", (err))
            cancel?(err)
        }
    }
    
    func isFollowingUser(withUID uid: String, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> (), withCancel cancel: ((Error) -> ())?) {
        guard let currentLoggedInUserId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        
        Database.database().reference().child("following").child(currentLoggedInUserId).child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let isFollowing = snapshot.value as? Int, isFollowing == 1 {
                completion(true)
            } else {
                completion(false)
            }
            
        }) { (err) in
            print("Failed to check if following:", err)
            cancel?(err)
        }
    }
    
    func followUser(withUID uid: String, completion: @escaping (Error?) -> ()) {
        guard let currentLoggedInUserId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        
        let values = [uid: 1]
        Database.database().reference().child("following").child(currentLoggedInUserId).updateChildValues(values) { (err, ref) in
            if let err = err {
                completion(err)
                return
            }
            
            let values = [currentLoggedInUserId: 1]
            Database.database().reference().child("followers").child(uid).updateChildValues(values) { (err, ref) in
                if let err = err {
                    completion(err)
                    return
                }
                completion(nil)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func unfollowUser(withUID uid: String, completion: @escaping (Error?) -> ()) {
        guard let currentLoggedInUserId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        
        Database.database().reference().child("following").child(currentLoggedInUserId).child(uid).removeValue { (err, _) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Failed to remove user from following:", err)
                completion(err)
                return
            }
            
            Database.database().reference().child("followers").child(uid).child(currentLoggedInUserId).removeValue(completionBlock: { (err, _) in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Failed to remove user from followers:", err)
                    completion(err)
                    return
                }
                completion(nil)
            })
        }
    }
    
    //MARK: Posts
    
    func createPost(withImage image: UIImage, caption: String, completion: @escaping (Error?) -> ()) {
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        
        let userPostRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(uid).childByAutoId()
        
        guard let postId = userPostRef.key else { return }
        
        Storage.storage().uploadPostImage(image: image, filename: postId) { (postImageUrl) in
            let values = ["imageUrl": postImageUrl, "caption": caption, "imageWidth": image.size.width, "imageHeight": image.size.height, "creationDate": Date().timeIntervalSince1970, "id": postId] as [String : Any]
            
            userPostRef.updateChildValues(values) { (err, ref) in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Failed to save post to database", err)
                    completion(err)
                    return
                }
                completion(nil)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func fetchPost(withUID uid: String, postId: String, completion: @escaping (Post) -> (), withCancel cancel: ((Error) -> ())? = nil) {
        guard let currentLoggedInUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(uid).child(postId)
        
        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            
            guard let postDictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
            
            Database.database().fetchUser(withUID: uid, completion: { (user) in
                var post = Post(user: user, dictionary: postDictionary)
                post.id = postId
                
                //check likes
                Database.database().reference().child("likes").child(postId).child(currentLoggedInUser).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                    if let value = snapshot.value as? Int, value == 1 {
                        post.likedByCurrentUser = true
                    } else {
                        post.likedByCurrentUser = false
                    }
                    
                    Database.database().numberOfLikesForPost(withPostId: postId, completion: { (count) in
                        post.likes = count
                        completion(post)
                    })
                }, withCancel: { (err) in
                    print("Failed to fetch like info for post:", err)
                    cancel?(err)
                })
            })
        })
    }
    
    func fetchAllPosts(withUID uid: String, completion: @escaping ([Post]) -> (), withCancel cancel: ((Error) -> ())?) {
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(uid)
        
        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            guard let dictionaries = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else {
                completion([])
                return
            }

            var posts = [Post]()

            dictionaries.forEach({ (postId, value) in
                Database.database().fetchPost(withUID: uid, postId: postId, completion: { (post) in
                    posts.append(post)
                    
                    if posts.count == dictionaries.count {
                        completion(posts)
                    }
                })
            })
        }) { (err) in
            print("Failed to fetch posts:", err)
            cancel?(err)
        }
    }
    
    func deletePost(withUID uid: String, postId: String, completion: ((Error?) -> ())? = nil) {
        Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(uid).child(postId).removeValue { (err, _) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Failed to delete post:", err)
                completion?(err)
                return
            }
            
            Database.database().reference().child("comments").child(postId).removeValue(completionBlock: { (err, _) in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Failed to delete comments on post:", err)
                    completion?(err)
                    return
                }
                
                Database.database().reference().child("likes").child(postId).removeValue(completionBlock: { (err, _) in
                    if let err = err {
                        print("Failed to delete likes on post:", err)
                        completion?(err)
                        return
                    }
                    
                    Storage.storage().reference().child("post_images").child(postId).delete(completion: { (err) in
                        if let err = err {
                            print("Failed to delete post image from storage:", err)
                            completion?(err)
                            return
                        }
                    })
                    
                    completion?(nil)
                })
            })
        }
    }
    
    func addCommentToPost(withId postId: String, text: String, completion: @escaping (Error?) -> ()) {
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        
        let values = ["text": text, "creationDate": Date().timeIntervalSince1970, "uid": uid] as [String: Any]
        
        let commentsRef = Database.database().reference().child("comments").child(postId).childByAutoId()
        commentsRef.updateChildValues(values) { (err, _) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Failed to add comment:", err)
                completion(err)
                return
            }
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
    
    func fetchCommentsForPost(withId postId: String, completion: @escaping ([Comment]) -> (), withCancel cancel: ((Error) -> ())?) {
        let commentsReference = Database.database().reference().child("comments").child(postId)
        
        commentsReference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            guard let dictionaries = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else {
                completion([])
                return
            }
            
            var comments = [Comment]()
            
            dictionaries.forEach({ (key, value) in
                guard let commentDictionary = value as? [String: Any] else { return }
                guard let uid = commentDictionary["uid"] as? String else { return }
                
                Database.database().fetchUser(withUID: uid) { (user) in
                    let comment = Comment(user: user, dictionary: commentDictionary)
                    comments.append(comment)
                    
                    if comments.count == dictionaries.count {
                        comments.sort(by: { (comment1, comment2) -> Bool in
                            return comment1.creationDate.compare(comment2.creationDate) == .orderedAscending
                        })
                        completion(comments)
                    }
                }
            })
            
        }) { (err) in
            print("Failed to fetch comments:", err)
            cancel?(err)
        }
    }
    
    //MARK: Utilities
    
    func numberOfPostsForUser(withUID uid: String, completion: @escaping (Int) -> ()) {
        Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            if let dictionaries = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
                completion(dictionaries.count)
            } else {
                completion(0)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func numberOfFollowersForUser(withUID uid: String, completion: @escaping (Int) -> ()) {
        Database.database().reference().child("followers").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            if let dictionaries = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
                completion(dictionaries.count)
            } else {
                completion(0)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func numberOfFollowingForUser(withUID uid: String, completion: @escaping (Int) -> ()) {
        Database.database().reference().child("following").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            if let dictionaries = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
                completion(dictionaries.count)
            } else {
                completion(0)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func numberOfLikesForPost(withPostId postId: String, completion: @escaping (Int) -> ()) {
        Database.database().reference().child("likes").child(postId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            if let dictionaries = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
                completion(dictionaries.count)
            } else {
                completion(0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have added the permissions in Firebase Database too:
[image]

Please tell where i am wrong and what i have to do to resolve this issue. Do i need to add child nodes manually in Firebase? If yes , then please guide with steps. I am having very less idea about FireBase database and I am still in a learning Phase. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: The security rules you're showing apply to Cloud Firestore, while the code in your question is accessing the Realtime Database. While both databases are part of Firebase, they're completely separate, and the security rules for one don't apply to the other. To fix the error, you will have to set the rules for the Realtime Database. For a walkthrough of how to do that, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52129163

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace below code with your firebase rules section:

```
    service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```